# Grafana - Alert does not trigger due to "nodata" / "NaN"

Tags: azure, grafana, nan, azure-monitor, no-data

Working on a Azure Managed Grafana setup with Azure Monitor as Data Source.

After adding an alert to a panel, the alert doesn´t trigger, and the panel looks like this:
[image]

The alert goes into a pending state and then resets to OK due to the NaN.

I assume this can be related to some polling intervals, but not sure if this is something Azure-related or what.

Any ideas on how it is best to solve this?

Alert looks like this:
[image]

And history like this:
[image]